# WSO2 APIM 2.0 Is it possible to customize or redirect to the /token url

Tags: oauth, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm migrating my APIs from an older system to WSO2 APIM 2.0.0 and am trying to make the switch transparent for my API users. I already migrated my existing consumer_key/secrets.

Is it possible to customize the /token API to something else?

In my old system, OAuth tokens are managed via a path like
/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken

Perhaps it's possible to map /oauth/client_credential/accesstoken to /token so that both can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution Bhathiya suggested works, just had to tweak the proxy endpoint

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPIProxy_" context="/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken">
<resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
    <inSequence>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                 <http uri-template="http://127.0.0.1:8280/token">
                    <timeout>
                        <duration>60000</duration>
                        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                    </timeout>
                </http>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the base path of /token api, you can either use some reverse proxy (eg. nginx) in front of api manager or create a proxy api like this inside api manager itself.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPIProxy_" context="/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
        <inSequence>
        <property name="uri.var.portnum" expression="get-property('https.nio.port')"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                     <http uri-template="https://localhost:{uri.var.portnum}/token">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>60000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers/>
</api>
```

You need to copy this to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/_WSO2AMTokenAPIProxy_.xml`

Comment: Thanks @Bhathiya, when I used that I got errors relating to the uri.var.portnum not being evaluated. I hard coded the localhost:8280 but then I got warnings relating to CSRF attach, thwarted.....